# I don't know how to read the output when using ranef against the output of gamm in the mgcv package

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

id:268 levels
group:10 levels
Fitted a mixed-effects model using gamm in the mgcv package. Fitted a generalized additive model for age and bmi, but could not read the output of the random effect using ranef
model:

```
    ilrgamm1 <-gamm(y~z1+z2+z3+s(age)+sex+s(bmi)+time,random=list(id=~1+time,group=~1),data=data,method = "REML")
```

At this time, there are mysterious things like g and g.0 in the output of ranef

```
    names(ranef(ilrgamm1$lme))
[1] "g"     "g.0"   "id"    "group"
```

```
    ranef(ilrgamm1$lme)[1:2]
$g
        Xr1       Xr2        Xr3       Xr4         Xr5      Xr6        Xr7        Xr8
1 0.1130164 0.6108163 -0.1332607 0.4076337 -0.04366085 2.503919 -0.9792176 -0.5911858

$g.0
        Xr.01     Xr.02     Xr.03      Xr.04      Xr.05    Xr.06      Xr.07    Xr.08
1/1 0.1983299 0.2758039 -1.100218 -0.4742126 -0.5449821 1.477916 -0.6329114 1.053759
```

What is Xr1 or Xr2?

Furthermore, there are 268 random effects in group, not 10.

```
$group
              (Intercept)
1/1/102/1    0.0172579674
1/1/103/1    0.0201196786
1/1/104/1   -0.0281116571
1/1/105/1   -0.0217217446
1/1/106/1    0.0124654493
1/1/108/1   -0.0282589006
1/1/109/1   -0.0499878886
1/1/110/1    0.0492600500
1/1/111/1    0.0507119068
1/1/113/1    0.0546332994
1/1/114/1    0.0393550975
1/1/115/1   -0.0148861329
1/1/116/1    0.0375339571
1/1/117/1    0.0148069805
1/1/118/1   -0.0351320894
1/1/119/1   -0.1195068445
1/1/120/1   -0.1160370216
1/1/121/1    0.0473366382
1/1/122/1   -0.0111156856
1/1/123/1    0.0076577605
1/1/124/1   -0.0042122818
1/1/125/1    0.0249031339
1/1/126/1   -0.1207996724
1/1/127/1    0.0275137051
1/1/128/1   -0.0004621387
1/1/130/1   -0.0080189325
1/1/132/1   -0.0147162203
1/1/133/1    0.0019108355
1/1/134/1    0.0048134559
1/1/135/1   -0.0275929191
1/1/136/1    0.0024070977
1/1/138/1   -0.0364971159
1/1/139/1   -0.0250644476
1/1/140/1   -0.0161684667
1/1/143/1    0.0097684438
1/1/144/1   -0.0254024942
1/1/145/1   -0.0308170535
1/1/146/1   -0.0314913020
1/1/147/1    0.0047849092
1/1/148/1    0.0398563674
1/1/149/1   -0.0328543231
1/1/201/2   -0.0386289339
1/1/202/2   -0.0164038050
1/1/203/2   -0.0310222871
1/1/204/2   -0.0465893084
1/1/206/2   -0.0639166021
1/1/207/2    0.0178124681
1/1/208/2   -0.0215777533
1/1/209/2   -0.0008097909
1/1/211/2   -0.0276369553
1/1/218/2   -0.0233586483
1/1/219/2   -0.0381510950
1/1/220/2   -0.0245044572
1/1/221/2    0.0257439303
1/1/222/2   -0.0526194229
1/1/223/2   -0.0598638388
1/1/224/2   -0.0564427102
1/1/226/2   -0.0682312455
1/1/227/2    0.0025178471
1/1/228/2    0.0050413163
1/1/229/2    0.0006566180
1/1/230/2   -0.0394159991
1/1/233/2   -0.0339136266
1/1/234/2   -0.0355879691
1/1/235/2    0.0264388355
1/1/236/2   -0.0190059575
1/1/237/2   -0.0466046545
1/1/238/2   -0.0103843873
1/1/239/2    0.0030630609
1/1/242/2   -0.0385347399
1/1/246/2   -0.0233604289
1/1/247/2   -0.0549077802
1/1/249/2   -0.0309410264
1/1/250/2   -0.0138412118
1/1/251/2   -0.0236995292
1/1/252/2   -0.0263367786
1/1/253/2   -0.0158340565
1/1/254/2   -0.0003306973
1/1/255/2   -0.0106150344
1/1/256/2   -0.0223922258
1/1/258/2    0.0042958519
1/1/301/3    0.1100838962
1/1/302/3    0.0240153141
1/1/303/3    0.0403893185
1/1/306/3    0.0483381436
1/1/307/3   -0.0129870303
1/1/309/3    0.0173975588
1/1/310/3   -0.0189250961
1/1/313/3    0.0357035256
1/1/315/3    0.0012214394
1/1/316/3    0.0325373842
1/1/317/3   -0.0085589305
1/1/319/3    0.0524899049
1/1/321/3    0.0416124283
1/1/322/3    0.0095534385
1/1/325/3    0.0321591953
1/1/326/3   -0.0054073693
1/1/327/3    0.0050364482
1/1/328/3    0.0531385640
1/1/331/3    0.0232251446
1/1/332/3    0.0189221949
1/1/333/3   -0.0181158192
1/1/334/3   -0.0359340965
1/1/335/3    0.0083524511
1/1/336/3   -0.0118781160
1/1/337/3   -0.0085829648
1/1/338/3    0.0095829746
1/1/401/4   -0.0512378233
1/1/402/4   -0.0219261499
1/1/403/4   -0.0160446585
1/1/407/4    0.0017872369
1/1/408/4   -0.0371254332
1/1/409/4    0.0303154843
1/1/411/4   -0.0026150821
1/1/412/4    0.1418719283
1/1/414/4   -0.0556019328
1/1/415/4    0.0073027068
1/1/416/4   -0.0122557311
1/1/417/4    0.0367134933
1/1/418/4   -0.0253763258
1/1/419/4   -0.0203686506
1/1/421/4   -0.0187932155
1/1/422/4   -0.0189659510
1/1/423/4   -0.0306159126
1/1/424/4    0.0273308724
1/1/425/4    0.0040657657
1/1/426/4    0.0312199779
1/1/429/4    0.0036135869
1/1/430/4   -0.0256442792
1/1/433/4    0.0438767257
1/1/434/4    0.0150299855
1/1/435/4   -0.0058240553
1/1/436/4    0.0028309330
1/1/437/4   -0.0023443246
1/1/438/4    0.0115472464
1/1/439/4   -0.0071635162
1/1/441/4   -0.0187692003
1/1/442/4   -0.0301687031
1/1/443/4   -0.0054707553
1/1/501/5    0.0233900218
1/1/502/5    0.0270437356
1/1/503/5   -0.0505494678
1/1/504/5   -0.0555547708
1/1/506/5   -0.0232974224
1/1/508/5   -0.0316901016
1/1/510/5    0.0498275109
1/1/511/5    0.0140125034
1/1/513/5   -0.1284098189
1/1/514/5    0.0336408919
1/1/515/5   -0.0328592365
1/1/516/5   -0.0264024730
1/1/601/6   -0.0064048726
1/1/602/6    0.0136098007
1/1/603/6    0.0437196138
1/1/604/6    0.0685239133
1/1/605/6   -0.0141230573
1/1/606/6    0.0555226687
1/1/607/6   -0.0411745650
1/1/608/6    0.0219745785
1/1/609/6   -0.0045706685
1/1/610/6   -0.0176662070
1/1/611/6    0.0408741543
1/1/612/6    0.0187626096
1/1/613/6    0.0561545743
1/1/614/6    0.0284241671
1/1/615/6    0.0157012751
1/1/616/6    0.0496079608
1/1/701/7   -0.0398327297
1/1/702/7   -0.0140910866
1/1/705/7    0.0286548362
1/1/706/7    0.0369761615
1/1/708/7    0.0116733825
1/1/709/7    0.0001330362
1/1/710/7    0.0274371733
1/1/711/7    0.0090225922
1/1/712/7    0.0765875063
1/1/713/7    0.0148952419
1/1/714/7   -0.0054933850
1/1/716/7    0.0043641233
1/1/717/7   -0.0119174808
1/1/719/7    0.0010953154
1/1/723/7   -0.0371240564
1/1/801/8    0.0636698316
1/1/803/8    0.0246677751
1/1/804/8   -0.0445965919
1/1/806/8   -0.0289816619
1/1/807/8    0.0076561215
1/1/808/8    0.0237686430
1/1/809/8    0.0450896739
1/1/810/8    0.0149585857
1/1/811/8    0.0075693911
1/1/812/8    0.0085475577
1/1/813/8   -0.0136763527
1/1/814/8    0.0117384418
1/1/815/8    0.0067855948
1/1/816/8    0.0140344652
1/1/817/8    0.0103800524
1/1/818/8   -0.0361848876
1/1/819/8    0.0449431626
1/1/820/8   -0.0092320086
1/1/822/8   -0.0404730405
1/1/823/8   -0.0494073578
1/1/824/8   -0.0029941736
1/1/825/8   -0.0145742585
1/1/826/8   -0.0314564014
1/1/828/8    0.0183565957
1/1/829/8    0.0288121410
1/1/830/8    0.0286684412
1/1/831/8    0.0059331890
1/1/832/8    0.0341139486
1/1/833/8    0.0386864016
1/1/834/8    0.0147205534
1/1/835/8   -0.0031409478
1/1/901/9    0.0660687434
1/1/902/9    0.0564001190
1/1/903/9    0.0756466936
1/1/904/9    0.0096398307
1/1/905/9    0.0221015690
1/1/906/9    0.0046220720
1/1/907/9    0.0412366347
1/1/908/9    0.0284303878
1/1/909/9    0.0452359853
1/1/910/9   -0.0195940019
1/1/911/9   -0.0154676475
1/1/912/9    0.0184574647
1/1/913/9    0.0460445032
1/1/914/9   -0.0067133484
1/1/915/9   -0.0087355534
1/1/916/9   -0.0043938763
1/1/917/9   -0.0470434649
1/1/919/9    0.0794927553
1/1/920/9    0.0555903561
1/1/921/9   -0.0036186615
1/1/922/9    0.0078238313
1/1/923/9    0.0143975055
1/1/924/9    0.0731162776
1/1/925/9   -0.0065668921
1/1/926/9    0.0549429919
1/1/927/9    0.0368946293
1/1/928/9    0.0247474240
1/1/929/9   -0.0404517417
1/1/930/9   -0.0076552298
1/1/1001/10  0.0117082112
1/1/1002/10  0.0068444544
1/1/1003/10  0.0327977955
1/1/1004/10  0.0071551344
1/1/1005/10 -0.0052717304
1/1/1006/10  0.0483668189
1/1/1007/10 -0.0167403419
1/1/1008/10 -0.0364566907
1/1/1009/10 -0.0254350538
1/1/1010/10  0.0504571167
1/1/1011/10 -0.0039537094
1/1/1012/10 -0.0054692797
1/1/1013/10  0.0224140597
1/1/1014/10 -0.0310392331
1/1/1015/10 -0.0498130767
1/1/1016/10 -0.0223939677
1/1/1017/10  0.0041103780
1/1/1018/10  0.0880528857
1/1/1019/10 -0.0467056887
1/1/1022/10 -0.0769873686
1/1/1025/10 -0.0229126779
1/1/1028/10 -0.0340772236
1/1/1029/10 -0.0251866535
1/1/1030/10  0.0307034344
1/1/1031/10 -0.0369165146
1/1/1035/10 -0.0056637857
```

Why not 10 types, which is the number of levels in group?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you're using `gamm()` instead of `gam()`? Also, why list time as both a fixed and random effect?

If there aren't reasons for these choices, then one possible solution could be to fit your model as `ilrgamm1 <- gam(y~z1+z2+z3+s(age)+sex+s(bmi)+s(time, bs="re"), data=data, method = "REML")` - the `s(time, bs="re")` is indicating that time is a random effect.

Then you can use `summary(ilrgamm1)` to look at your results, and partial effects plots in plot.gam() or with ggpredict to visualize trends in your smoothed variables.

Comment: I thought it was a fixed effect and a random effect based on ID, but am I wrong?  I use gamm because I have two result variables and I want to use logistic regression for the other one.  Also, is s(time, bs="re") supposed to mean (1+time|ID) or (1|group) in lmer? @hdiza

Comment: With multiple random effects, especially where the number of levels is over 100 or so, you are going to start hitting a computational bottleneck with `gam()` because it isn’t currently able to exploit the sparse nature of the model matrix for the random effects. That’s a good reason to prefer `gamm()` or `gamm4::gamm4()` over `gam()`. If you want to estimate a population level effect of `time` then you need to include it is both the fixed and random components of the model.

Comment: Sounds like maybe gamm() is what you want then if you have +200 levels of your random effect. For future reference though, in gam, s(time, bs="re") is equivalent to (1|time) in lmer.

Comment: Thanks.  
By the way, do you know what the random effects `g` and `g.0` mean?  @GavinSimpson @hdiza